# Return false instead throw exception

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
public static function get($action, $param = null) {
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => "GET"
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);

    $params = '';
    foreach($param as $key => $value)
        $params .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    trim($params, '&');

    $result = file_get_contents(self::$url . $action . '?' . $params, false, $context);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}
```

The problem is: when i provide wrong url to `file_get_contents`, it throw error (Exception).
But, i want to return false instead without throw error.
How can i do this?

Comment: try catch block within that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `try {} catch {}` in order to catch the exception and do something in this case.

```
try {
   $result = file_get_contents(self::$url . $action . '?' . $params, false, $context);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply surround it with a [`try-catch`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) block:

```
public static function get($action, $param = null) {
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => "GET"
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);

    $params = '';
    foreach($param as $key => $value)
        $params .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    trim($params, '&');

    try {
        $result = file_get_contents(self::$url . $action . '?' . $params, false, $context);
        return json_decode($result, true);
    } catch(Exception $exc) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`try` makes PHP exception-aware one could say: if an exception is *thrown* inside the `try` block, PHP will execute the `catch` block and here `$exc` will contain details about the thrown exception.